# Labeling an equation without making it center aligned

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I know that we can use the `\tag{label}` command to label an equation. However using this makes an equation center aligned. How do I keep the equation left aligned and still have a tag for the equation? I was trying something like `\displaystyle <equation code in latex>\tag{label}` but it did not work the way I want.

**Update**: Please note that my environment is a blog which uses MathJax for rendering latex code. math.stackexchange also uses the same MathJax engine.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: MathJax questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @Werner: Sorry I was not aware as this is my first question here.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need `fleqn` but here all `equation`s will be left aligned.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}   % just for demo
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    x=y
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

On the other hand, you can use `flalign` from `amsmath` too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}   % just for demo
\begin{document}
  \begin{flalign}
    &x=y&
  \end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try to use the flalign as I want to typeset in my blog using MathJax.

Comment: I tried using flalign in mathjax (by typing a sample question in math.stackexchange.com) but it does not seem to work.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh No idea about mathjax and I am afraid that mathjax is off topic on this site.

Comment: Ok no issues, I tried an alternative approach with array environment and created a table with two columns, first column as left aligned which contains the equation and second column which is right aligned and has the label. This seems to solve the problem although it is messy.